# Getting Users API access in nodejs AppEngine environment with Identity Aware Proxy

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-iap

I have a nodejs app deployed on AppEngine with IAP enabled, so right now access to its endpoints is protected against users outside of the project's IAM and I get the "x-goog-authenticated-user-id", "x-goog-authenticated-user-email" and another jwt assertion x-goog signed header, just like it should be (as detailed here https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto).

In certain AppEngine environments (so far Python, Java, Go) it seems you are able to use some already provided libraries to get more information about the user with Users API, however the nodejs page is disabled (here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/users/), there seems to be no indication of what should be done there. Any ideas?

If there is no straight forward way around it would I be able to have an app engine environment that also exposes for example the Python libraries for Users API so that I can wrap around them and use them in my nodejs app?

Answer (score 4):

The Users API [isn't supported for Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/authenticating-users). Instead, you can get the identity from the [`x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion` header](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto#retrieve_the_user_identity).

We don't currently have a code sample for Node.js, though [this](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) looks like one reasonable approach. (Disclaimer: I'm not a Node user, and don't know enough about Node JWT libraries to endorse any of them in particular.)

Comment: yeah, the identity is both in the jwt assertion header as is int he other x-goog headers taken separately. however I thought there would be more to the identity of a user than the information provided there: email, id and "nickname". for example I was looking into whether I could get the user's various roles or appartenance to groups

Comment: Ah, not currently. What you can do today is use something like https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/ to check group memberships from inside your application.

Comment: Yes, I used that at some point when integrating with a GSuite account, I don't remember clearly but I think I had some trouble doing the same with GCP IAM though. It seems the "member accounts" over there have much less information, should they be accessible using GSuite admin sdk as well?

Answer (score 0):

Update for the current state:

There is currently a
[Identity-Aware Proxy Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/iap/latest) for Node JS.